# Jersey 2.*. How to replace InjectableProvider and AbstractHttpContextInjectable of Jersey 1.*

Tags: java, dependency-injection, jersey, jax-rs

I would like to create a class whose objects can be injected using the `@Context` annotation (or better yet a custom annotation for cases where I need to pass an argument to the annotation) into resource methods. In Jersey 1.* I would have used `InjectableProvider` (in my case together with `AbstractHttpContextInjectable`). What I'm trying to achieve is something like `@Auth` [[1](https://github.com/codahale/dropwizard/tree/master/dropwizard-auth/src/main/java/com/codahale/dropwizard/auth)] from *dropwizard* (which uses Jersey 1.7).

The injection capabilities of Jersey were replaced by HK2 as far as I know and I could not find any example of what I'm describing.

Edit: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18488622/jersey-2-custom-injectionresolver-and-a-http-get-method-should-not-consu) for further problems I have encountered while trying to follow Michal's guide.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to implement [InjectionResolver<T>](https://hk2-project.github.io//apidocs/org/glassfish/hk2/api/InjectionResolver.html) interface from HK2. Take a look at existing implementations that are present in Jersey workspace:

- [ContextInjectionResolver](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/core-common/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/internal/inject/ContextInjectionResolver.java) handling `@Context`
- [ParamInjectionResolver](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/core-server/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/server/internal/inject/ParamInjectionResolver.java) handling `@PathParam`, `@QueryParam`, ... (via it's subclasses)
- [AutowiredInjectResolver](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/ext/spring4/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/server/spring/AutowiredInjectResolver.java) handling `@Autowired`

Once you have this, you need to extend [AbstractBinder](https://hk2-project.github.io/apidocs/org/glassfish/hk2/utilities/binding/AbstractBinder.html) from HK2 and bind your `InjectionResolver` via it's `#configure()` method:

```
public class MyResolverBinder extends AbstractBinder {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(MyInjectionResolver.class)
                .to(new TypeLiteral<InjectionResolver<MyAnnotation>>() {})
                .in(Singleton.class);
    }
}
```

... and register an instance of this binder in your application class (or via [feature](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Feature.html)):

`Feature`:

```
public class MyFeature implements Feature {

    @Override
    public boolean configure(final FeatureContext context) {
        context.register(new MyResolverBinder());
        return true;
    }
}
```

register `MyFeature` into `Application`:

```
public class JaxRsApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        final HashSet<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        classes.add(MyFeature.class);
        // Register other providers or resources.
        return classes;
    }
}
```

register `MyResolverBinder` or `Feature` in the `ResourceConfig`

```
new ResourceConfig()
        // Register either MyFeature
        .register(MyFeature.class)
        // or MyResolverBinder
        .register(new MyResolverBinder())
        // Register other providers or resources
        .packages("my.package");
```

Comment: Thanks! That seems to be exactly what I need.

Comment: Michal, I tried to follow your guide, but I have encountered a weird warning "... A HTTP GET method ... should not consume any entity.". I'm not sure what to make of that (see edit of my question for more details). Do you have any ideas as to what might be causing it? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, it's unclear to me how to create an object given, say, the `ContainerRequestContext` and how to correctly dispose of the injected object, e.g., by calling `close()`. I can't find any example online, do you have suggestions?

Comment: `ContainerRequestContext` is created for you by Jersey (you can access it in the provider). If you need to dispose the object try implementing a `@PreDestroy` method.

Comment: Am I the only one that has a feeling this has gone from very simple and concise in Jersey 1.x to extremely overly engineer and cumbersome in 2.x?

Answer (score 4):

Providing an implementation of `InjectionResolver` only helps with *injection*, not when resolving values for the parameters of a resource method.

At least with Jersey 2.11, you need to define a `ValueFactoryProvider` annotated with `@Provider`.

```java
@Provider
public class MyValueFactoryProvider implements ValueFactoryProvider {

    @Inject
    private MyFactory factory;

    @Override
    public Factory<?> getValueFactory(Parameter parameter) {
        if (parameter.getAnnotation(MyAnnotationParam.class) != null) {
            return factory;
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public PriorityType getPriority() {
        return Priority.NORMAL;
    }

}
```

If you also want to get the value injected in, e.g., members and constructor parameters, then InjectionResolver works well.