# Jersey 2.*. Custom InjectionResolver and "A HTTP GET method ... should not consume any entity"

Tags: java, dependency-injection, jersey, jax-ws, jax-rs

I have followed Michal's guide from his answer to this question [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18463311/jersey-2-how-to-replace-injectableprovider-and-abstracthttpcontextinjectable)] on implementing custom annotation for injecting arbitrary things into resource methods. This (gist) [[2](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/389e1e8064174bdcd102)] contains a minimalistic testbed adapted from the `jersey-quickstart-grizzly2` archetype. I will refer to it in the following text.

I encountered a few problems:

1. My resolver is parametrized type (or at least it would make things much more cleaner, in my opinion) and thus I can not `bind` it in my binder the way Michal suggests.

   ```
   // Instead of the suggested:
   // bind(MyInjectionResolver.class).to(new TypeLiteral<InjectionResolver<MyAnnotation>>() {}).in(Singleton.class);
   // I do:
   bind(myInjectionResolverObject).to(new TypeLiteral<InjectionResolver<MyAnnotation>>() {});
   ```
2. When I use `MyAnnotation` in the resource method, I get the following warning on server start-up (but the server still starts):

   ```
   WARNING: The following warnings have been detected: WARNING: A HTTP GET method, public java.lang.String com.example.MyResource.get02(java.lang.Integer,java.lang.String), should not consume any entity.
   ```
3. When I request the resource (`curl -X GET http://localhost:8080/myresource/01/aa`), I get `02: value = aa; providedValue = null` instead of the expected `02: value = aa; providedValue = 123`.
4. The `MyResolver.resolve` method is never executed (but `MyBinder.configure` is executed).
5. (This does not concern the testbed application, but I encounter the problem in a slightly more complicated code: the resource method is never executed and the server responds with `500 No content to map to Object due to end of input`)

Any ideas as to what I might be doing wrong?