# Mocking spring bean in jersey resource

Tags: java, spring, rest, mocking, jersey

Im using @Autowire in Jerse Resources and spring interation. Now i want to be able to use mock 
object on Autowired fields.,

I was able to do this in Jersey 1.17, but on 2.2 i could not find any documentations.

I have tired some thing like this 
[Jersey 2.*. How to replace InjectableProvider and AbstractHttpContextInjectable of Jersey 1.*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18463311/jersey-2-how-to-replace-injectableprovider-and-abstracthttpcontextinjectable/18464901#18464901)

And provided own SpringComponent when setting up the container., but this does either work.,

```
Example: 
@Path("/myresource")
public class MyResource {

 @Autowired
 private ConfigurationApi configurationApi;

 @GET
 @Produces("text/plain")
 public String getIt() {
 boolean isTrue = configurationApi.isEnabled("aconfig");
 return "Hi there!: configuration is " + isTrue;
}
```

In jersey 1.17 i could do somthing like this:

```
return new WebAppDescriptor.Builder("rest.resource")
                .contextPath("application")
                .servletClass(SpringServlet.class)
                .servletPath("api")
                .contextParam("contextClass", "rest.resource.test.spring.MockableContext")
                .contextParam(SpringServlet.CONTEXT_CONFIG_LOCATION, "context.poc-test.xml")
                .contextListenerClass(ContextLoaderListener.class)
                .build();
```

And then later on the actual test i could add mock object to the context class by a hash map.,

Any help is appriciated .,

Comment: How do you load your Spring context? Do you use SpringJUnit4ClassRunner? If yes, you can define your mock bean for ConfigurationApi in a Spring xml file.