# how to secure jersey REST?

Tags: java, api, tomcat, jersey, restful-authentication

I know that this may be a duplicate question,but I could not find any answer that satisfies my need.
I have RESTful API using jersey , and i want to secure them with basic authentication with different roles.

so i need :

1 - secure the API with basic authentication

2- the username and the password should be stored in the DB.

3- allow different roles (in: admin, support , basic ..)

Note : i'm using Tomcat 7 server

Please advice

Thanks

Comment: In this question you've got several answers that apply to your needs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23231511/jersey-2-how-to-create-custom-http-param-binding. (Although I particularly like my answer...) From the subject of the question it not obvious that answers yours, but trust me it does. Hope it helps

Comment: @lrnzcig you should add this as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this question you've got several answers that apply to your needs: [jersey 2: How to create custom HTTP param binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23231511/jersey-2-how-to-create-custom-http-param-binding)

From the subject of the question it not obvious that answers yours, but trust me it does.
(I particularly like my answer, however it is not the most voted.)
Hope it helps.